# ionic2 rollup build failed: bundle prod failed: Cannot call a namespace ('io')

Tags: socket.io, ionic2

after upgrade ionic2 in the new project (from scratch) ..
cannot use **socket.io**.

```
    import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

...    

    this.socket = io(url);
          ....
```

build failed: **bundle prod failed:  Cannot call a namespace ('io')**

*in previous version it was solved by:*

```
 typings install dt~socket.io-client --save --global
```

The error print  and configurations below:

```
[12:19:27]  bundle prod failed:  Cannot call a namespace ('io')
[12:19:27]  Error: Cannot call a namespace ('io')
    at error (/*****************/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5404:12)
    at CallExpression.bind (/*****************/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5837:5)
    at /*****************/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5149:50
    at AssignmentExpression.eachChild (/*****************/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5166:5)
    at AssignmentExpression.bind (/*****************/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5149:7)
    at AssignmentExpression.bind (/*****************/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5509:23)
    at /*****************/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5149:50
    at ExpressionStatement.eachChild (/*****************/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5166:5)
    at ExpressionStatement.bind (/*****************/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5149:7)
    at BlockStatement.bind (/*****************/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5615:9)
Error running ionic app script "build": Error: Cannot call a namespace ('io')

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node" "/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "run-script" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

....

**package.json**

```
    {
...
      "dependencies": {
        "@ionic/storage": "^1.0.3",
        "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
        "ionic-native": "^2.0.3",
        "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^1.5.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "latest",
        "typescript": "^2.0.3"
      },
...
      "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
      ],
      "cordovaPlatforms": []
    }
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "socket.io-client": "registry:dt/socket.io-client#1.4.4+20160317120654"
  }
}
```

## System Info

- Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0-beta.3
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
- OS: Distributor ID:  Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Node Version: v6.7.0

Answer (score 2):

The syntax

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
```

..is not standard, you will have runtime errors:

Keep the syntax `import * as io from 'socket.io-client'`, then in Typescript cast io as any to call the default method:

```
    var ioFunc = (io as any).default ? (io as any).default : io;
    this.socket = ioFunc(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution: no wildcard import...

**import io from 'socket.io-client';**

instead

import * as io from 'socket.io-client'